# How can flutter/dart in android studio codeInsight/Content Assist like java

Tags: flutter

when the developer android app in the android studio, the code insight is very user-friendly. I can just write a class in another package and the android studio shows the possible class and you just select it.

But when I write dart language code using flutter SDK in an android studio.
there is no code assistant like writing java.
so how can I make an android studio have that function when I write dart/flutter?

---

added in 2019/07/17
[image]

---

[image]
as you can see in the image above, the android studio has some code assistant for flutter/dart,
but it is not enough for me, what I want is I can automatically import some dart files when I just write that class(my own class, not from the flutter SDK)

Comment: Did you install the Flutter plugin in Android Studio ?

Comment: Yes,i did  install Flutter plugin.